# Display file imports/usage used in a python file

Tags: python, maya

I was wondering if there are any sort of python codeing etc that will displays the files imports/used locations in a python file?

Eg. TestA.py contains 3 files from 3 different directory

- Import01 : /u/ext/TestA/UI
- Import02 : /u/ext/TestA/src
- Import03 : /user_data/setup/localImports

And hence, while executing the coding, it will displays the list of directories used in the python file?

I am asking as I am working on several (and maybe tons, in the future) scripts that are heavily involved in Maya, there are times in which when I located the path but they are the wrong ones (with same name) and is actually located in another path

Comment: Yes, there is. The module system is very easy to hack, and I think you can easily write a custom loader to keep track of the directories used - but I don't have the time to post a proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to `module`

```
import inspect
frame = inspect.currentframe()
if frame and frame.f_back:
    print('module "{}" is imported by "{}"'.format(__file__, frame.f_back.f_locals['__file__']))
```

If `module_a.py` contains the code above, and `main.py` imports it. the output is

```
module "/path/to/module_a.py" is imported by "/path/to/main.py"
```

[As documented](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/inspect.html), this answer may not be an exact solution. Because if not supported, returns None.

> CPython implementation detail: This function relies on Python stack frame support in the interpreter, which isn’t guaranteed to exist in all implementations of Python. If running in an implementation without Python stack frame support this function returns None.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I tried but it does not seems to be working. Cause this python file I am working on, has modules that was imported from the server (custom scripts) and even as I saved out a file, it does not seems to be able to work.

Comment: Additionally, is it possible to check without running the code? Eg. if I input in the directory of the file (that I want to know the modules of the path it contains), it will displays it?

Answer (score 1):

At any point in when the code is running, you can determine the origin of a module by checking it's **file** attribute:

```
import sys
for name, each_mod  in sys.modules.items():
    try:
        print name, each_mod.__file__
    except AttributeError:  # = built in module or dll
        print "?"
```

To check the imports without running the code, you'd need do more complex analysis: Here's an example method that could probably be adapted to figure it out :http://www.tarind.com/depgraph.html

You could also create a custom [ModuleFinder](https://docs.python.org/2/library/modulefinder.html) that printed out file sources as imports are processed.  Something like this, which prints out name of py/pyc files when trying to load them.

```
import os
import sys
import imp
import ihooks

class ReportingFinder(object):
    """Find modules collected in a shelve archive."""

    def __init__(self, path_entry):
        self.path_entry = path_entry
        if not os.path.isdir(path_entry):
            raise ImportError

    def find_module(self, fullname, path=None):
        for suffix in (".py", ".pyc"):
            test_path = os.path.join(self.path_entry, fullname + suffix)
            print test_path
            if os.path.exists(test_path):
                print "attemnpting to load from %s" % test_path
                return self
        return None

    def load_module(self, name):
        stuff = imp.find_module(name)
        return ihooks.FancyModuleLoader(verbose=1).load_module(name, stuff)

sys.path_hooks.insert(0, ReportingFinder)
```

**HACK WARNING!!!!** Please be aware this code is a quick diagnostic hack! Don't use it for production :)  Among other flaws, it will print out py path names even if the code comes from the pyc, and it's dumb about packages -- I only provided it because it sounds like you're using single-file scripts rather than packages.  It is handy for catching imported modules as they get loaded. It won't print out the names of zip files.

It sounds like the real problem is having too many competing paths: you should try to get down to as few as you can so that there are fewer suprises.

Comment: this seems to be the one that I am looking for. Never thought that it will be this complex as I presume that just writing an external coding to show the modules would do the trick. Will try it out and see if it is viable for my usage. Thanks!